# Insert Into SQL Statement results in Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Tags: mysql, sql, select, union, sql-insert

I have an empty table, DatabaseStudents2, composed of three columns: StudentName, StudentEmail, ClassName. The data that I want to insert into this table are all stored into three separate, one column tables. I am using the following insert statement:

```
insert into DatabaseStudents2(StudentName, StudentEmail, ClassName)
       select names from StudentNames
       union
       select email from studentEmail
       union
       select clname from ClassName;
```

However, when I try and execute this I am getting the "Column count doesn't match value count at row 1" error. I am unsure why because I have three column names and three select statements so I don't see how my column count doesn't match why value count. Please advise. Thank you!

Comment: UNION returns only 1 column. You need joins.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  What are you trying to insert?

Comment: Hoin is the right choice, but when your tables have only one column how do you correlate all tables. You have to make a rowcount to join them.

Answer (score 2):

I need more information to answer this question.
May you share the definition (DDL) from StudentNames, studentemail and ClassName tables?

Anyway, I made a sample to show you:

```
create table DatabaseStudents2 (StudentName varchar(25), 
StudentEmail varchar(50), ClassName varchar(50));
create table StudentNames (id int, names varchar(25));
create table StudentEmail (id int, id_student int, email varchar(50));
create table ClassName (id int, id_student int, clname varchar(50));
```

The tables StudentEmail and ClassName has a column 'id_student' to identify the student and it's used to join.

Let's insert some rows. Students:

```
insert into StudentNames values (1, "John");
insert into StudentNames values (2, "Maria");
```

Now e-mail:

```
insert into StudentEmail values (1, 1, 'john@email.com');
insert into StudentEmail values (2, 1, 'john.secondmail@email.com');
insert into StudentEmail values (3, 2, 'maria@email.com');
```

The student 'John' have 2 e-mail. The first column identify the e-mail and the second identify the student.

Now class:

```
insert into ClassName values (1, 1, 'First Class');
insert into ClassName values (2, 2, 'Second Class');
```

Selecting these 3 table with join:

```
select s.names, e.email, c.clname from StudentNames s 
inner join StudentEmail e on s.id = e.id_student
inner join ClassName c on s.id = c.id_student;

+-------+---------------------------+--------------+
| names | email                     | clname       |
+-------+---------------------------+--------------+
| John  | john@email.com            | First Class  |
| John  | john.secondmail@email.com | First Class  |
| Maria | maria@email.com           | Second Class |
+-------+---------------------------+--------------+
```

Finally, the insert that you want:

```
insert into DatabaseStudents2 (StudentName, StudentEmail, ClassName) 
select s.names, e.email, c.clname from StudentNames s 
inner join StudentEmail e on s.id = e.id_student 
inner join ClassName c on s.id = c.id_student;
```

Let me know if i helped you.